# Retrieving the non-relativistic formulas for electric and magnetic fields from relativistic formulas

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, field-theory

I was checking the formulas for the electric and magnetic fields components **E** and **B** given in this link from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#Transformation_of_the_fields_between_inertial_frames
By the end of the section, they convert these formulas from the relativistic to the non-relativistic aspect by just approximating that the Lorentz factor becomes very small, since $v<<c$. I was thinking if there is any way to derive these formulas by applying a Taylor expansion on the gamma-factor. Is this possible, and if yes, could someone write me how any of these vectors would transform to non-relativistic approach? I already know how to do the Taylor expansion of the gamma factor, but afterward, I cannot figure out the calculations.
Any idea or help is very appreciated.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what the small v approximation is, a Taylor expansion of the gamma-factor, and any other dependencies on v.

Comment: @ggcg yes, but if I apply the Taylor expansion on the gamma factor, the ratio $v/c$ would still be present, so how can I come to a non-relativistic approach then?

Comment: Non-relativistic doesn’t mean $v/c$ is absent. The gamma factor gives $(v/c)^2$ terms, which you can ignore.

Comment: @G.Smith well, there's no $v/c$ in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#Non-relativistic_approximations
I'm assuming these are the results I should get in the end.
And what's the meaning of using a Taylor expansion when you still ignore $v^2/c$$^2$?

Comment: You’re being too literal. There is a $\mathbf{v}$ in each equation, but no $v^2$. Sometimes there is no $c$, and sometimes there is $c^2$; this is just because of the use of non-Gaussian units. In Gaussian units, every $v$ would be divided by $c$.

Comment: There is no point in using a Taylor series on gamma if you want equations accurate only to first order in $v$. That is why they approximated gamma as 1.

Comment: A nonrelativistic transformation usually keeps first order in $v$, but not higher, because this is similar to the Galilean transformation $x’=x-vt$.

Comment: So to “derive” those equations, you literally just set gamma to 1 in the equations higher up.

Comment: I understand it now. So the point of using Taylor expansion is to increase the accuracy of the resulting non-relativistic equations in higher orders and to avoid approximating gamma as 1. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. A more sophisticated example is in General Relativity. There is something called the post-Newtonian formalism in which the motion of gravitating particles is studied not exactly but to high orders of $v/c$.

Comment: Do you maybe know any good book that describes the post-Newtonian formalism?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Experiment-Gravitational-Physics-Revised/dp/0521439736

Comment: Expansions in $v/c$ are very useful when the exact solution cannot be found, as in the post-Newtonian formalism. They are not particularly useful in this electromagnetic field transformation, where the exact transformation *is* known and easily calculated. I’m not sure why Wikipedia even bothers with mentioning the nonrelativistic approximation.

Comment: Actually, the expression given in Wikipedia is wrong. You can’t just Taylor expand like that, it isn’t self consistent. For example, under their formula a boost by -v does _not_ undo a boost by v.

Comment: In fact, taking the Galilean limit of electromagnetism is far more subtle. There are actually two different self-consistent ways to do it. To learn more just search it up on this site, it’s been discussed before.